# Why does the SetScrollInfo() function sends a WM_SIZE message to WndProc()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Why does the SetScrollInfo() function sends a WM_SIZE message to WndProc() ?

**EDIT** Apparently, this is a bug in the WinAPI. The WM_SIZE message was being sent because I forgot to include the `WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL` styles in the window creation. Once that was corrected, the WM_SIZE isn't being sent anymore. Thanks.

Comment: It can alter the client size of the window.

Comment: It's not a bug I'd say, since it's documented behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a documented feature, it's likely not a bug.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx:

> **Remarks**
>
> If the `SetScrollPos` or `MoveWindow` function is called for a child window as a result of the `WM_SIZE` message, the `bRedraw` or `bRepaint` parameter should be nonzero to cause the window to be repainted.

Comment: In my case SetScrollPos() is called in WM_CREATE and the window in question is not a child. It's the app main window.