# Sending a WM_SIZE message programmatically

Tags: c, winapi

Is there something wrong in sending a `WM_SIZE` message programmatically, for example:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);
```

I don't care about the values of `wParam` and `lParam` (my `WM_SIZE` event handler does not use them).

What I want to do is to use the code inside the `WM_SIZE` event handler in other places in my program, but I don't want to replicate it, so I thought of just sending a `WM_SIZE` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to do is to use the code inside the WM_SIZE event handler in other places in my program, but I don't want to replicate it, so I thought of just sending a WM_SIZE message.

You can probably do this but it would, in my view, be a poor design.

Far better would be to move the code in your window's `WM_SIZE` handler into a separate function. Then you can call that function from anywhere in your program, including the `WM_SIZE` handler.

As a general rule, you should try to avoid putting all of your code in the window procedure. If you take that approach you will find that your window procedure becomes a giant wall of code and it will be very hard for you to read and understand it. And as you have found out, it becomes hard to re-use code when done that way. Try to move all of the cases of your window procedure into separate functions. Then the window procedure simply switches on the message and calls those separate functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong but the better way is to use [SetWindowPos()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with proper flags, it will call `WM_SIZE` instead of you.

Comment: but he doesn't actually want to resize so wouldn't it make more sense to just send WM_SIZE....despite it being a poor design and all.

Answer (score 1):

You can always programmatically send or post any message, it will be processed by the window procedure.

But you should be aware that WM_SIZE is just a notification message sent by the system to tell a window that its size was modified. **Sending that message will not make the window change its size**. The message is normally sent when `SetScrollPos` or `MoveWindow` are called.

Comment: What I want to do is to use the code inside the `WM_SIZE` event handler in other places in my program, but I don't want to replicate it, so I thought of just sending a `WM_SIZE` message.

Comment: @Tony: IMHO, it would be cleaner to put the common code in a function, and call it from wherever you want. Or if you want it to be called in the context of the window procedure, you should use a private message. You should think twice to *why* you need that. Manually sending WM_SIZE looks like *smelling* design.

Comment: Of course you can send/post any message to a window. But you should never suggest doing so, without a big warning sign, that reads: "DON'T!" You may get away with a fake `WM_SIZE`, where the handler doesn't care about the arguments, or current state. What about a `WM_CHAR` message, though, where its message handler calls `GetKeyState`? Or how about posting a `WM_QUIT` message, that behaves radically different from calling `PostQuitMessage`? There's lots more, that can go wrong.

Comment: Unable to repro `SetScrollPos` sending a `WM_SIZE` message to the owning wndproc. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251901/why-does-the-setscrollinfo-function-sends-a-wm-size-message-to-wndproc)